# Where is my logDebug/vlogDebug messages displayed?

Tags: java, servlets, atg

I'm trying to debug an ATG servlet and I am in the process of learning how to use the ATG Logging debug function. I checked the properties file of the servlet (I'm specifically debugging a checkout service pipeline) and I have determined that loggingDebug is enabled.

Throughout the pipeline I'm putting in the following code. As I understand it, this is the preferred method if I'm just trying to output a string rather than include a variable.

```
(isLoggingDebug()) {
            logDebug("Shipping address is not set.");
        }
```

Can someone advise that I'm using the correct logDebug method? And if I'm not mistaken, my output should be displayed in the terminal if my terminal is tailing the log file of the server instance, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're using the right logDebug() method. Few things to consider:

1. What scope did you've for the pipeline component?
2. You've mentioned checkout service pipeline, are you talking about the checkout pipeline? In that case, they are not servlets but processors
3. Are you sure your pipeline component is instantiated and invoked? You can place a loggingDebug on the constructor and see if that prints anything

If you can answer these questions, I can help better.

And yes, it should print on the server logs (where you see other messages of repository starting and such).

-Jags